# patch request using axios fail in directusCMS

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, directus

i am trying to send a patch request to update or maybe change the image in directus CMS.. (changing it require only id of the item and the file which is already solved.. in this link

[Make Multiple Post Requests In Axios then get all the response to make another request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566618/make-multiple-post-requests-in-axios-then-get-all-the-response-to-make-another-r))

below is the simplified code of it because the thing i am trying to achieve is making an item that have name, email, date, etc. then sending file or an image to the files ..

then i need to patch the item that i just made which is where i am not able to do yet..

for information only.. i am using gatsbyjs..

i have already tried it in postman and it works.. maybe there is something wrong with my code. thanks..

```
axios.patch( `${process.env.GATSBY_DIRECTUS_API_URL}/gemaclc/items/pendaftar/49?access_token=${process.env.GATSBY_DIRECTUS_TOKEN}`, {
    data: JSON.stringify( {
        kartu_keluarga: 1,
          
      
      }), 
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

i deleted JSON.stringify and it works

```
axios( `${process.env.GATSBY_DIRECTUS_API_URL}/gemaclc/items/pendaftar/50?access_token=${process.env.GATSBY_DIRECTUS_TOKEN}`, 
{
  method:"patch",
  data :{
        kartu_keluarga: 1,
        nama: "zidsadanaaa"
          
      
      }, 
  }
  
  )
```